# Sub class generics of class type in Typescript

Tags: java, typescript, class, generics, inheritance

I am trying to achieve something in Typescript. I will post the Java equivalent in hope that someone can help me with the Typescript version.

```
interface BaseChannel {
    void send();
}

public class SampleChannel implements BaseChannel {

    @Override
    public void send() {

    }
}

public class SampleDispatch {

     Class<? extends BaseChannel>[] getChannels() {
        Class<? extends BaseChannel>[] array = new Class[2];
        array[0] = SampleChannel.class;
        array[1] = BaseChannel.class;
        return array;
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are you going to *do* with the return value of `getChannels()`?  In TS the entire static type system is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) (like generics in TS) so there is no `BaseChannel` at all at runtime if that's an interface.  Class constructors do exist at runtime, so you can access `SampleChannel` but it has no `class` property.  Without knowing the intended use case it's hard to suggest how best to translate this into TS from Java.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```
interface BaseChannel {
    send();
}

class SampleChannel implements BaseChannel {

    constructor() {}
    send() {
        // do stuff
    }
}

class SampleDispatch {

    getChannels<T extends BaseChannel>(obj: T): BaseChannel {
        return new SampleChannel();
    }

}
```

I added a generic type parameter but your example do not need any generic